# right way to modify a variable of the main prgm in an aux prgm in python

Tags: python, global-variables

I can't seem to find the right way to do this. I have a main module with a variable `x` and an auxiliary module that must be able to update `x`.

The following does not work:

```
#main.py
import aux
x=0
aux.update()

#aux.py
import main
def update():
   main.x += 1
```

It seems to be possible with a `third` module holding `x`:

```
#main.py
import aux,third
third.x = 0
aux.update()

#aux.py
import third
def update():
   third.x += 1

#third.py
x = 0
```

Is this `third` module necessary? Is there a "better way"?

Comment: As a programmer you should try very, *very*, **very** hard not to use globals!

Comment: The `third` module *is* necessary. It gives you non-mutual imports, and something like a tree structure of modules.

Comment: ok so is it right? or is x considered a global variable here? Somebody told me to use classes and instances but i don't see how

Comment: Yes, both main.x and third.x are global variables. Class variables are also like globals, but instance variables are usually not considered global. Maybe its time for some more research into OOP, classes and instances.

Comment: I know what is a class and an instance, I just don't see how it solves my problem. And why is it so bad to use global variables?

Comment: So maybe it’s time for a new question on stack overflow. Also see [this](https://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad)

Comment: I guess if I aks this question I'll get marked as a duplicate.

Comment: So, what *is* the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Have my program split in two programs and a variable x that can be used by both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could write some sort of `class`, make an instance of it and pass that to your `update()` function:

```
#main.py
import aux

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x):
    self.x = x

third = Foo(0)
print(third.x)
aux.update(third)
print(third.x)


#aux.py
def update(instance):
   instance.x += 1
```

Output:

```
0
1
```

Comment: Ok thanks. Just to make sure I get it right: Say I name the class "Global_variables" instead of "Foo" and declare several parameters x,y,z...Then if I creat an instance "global_variables" and play around with "global_variables.x, global_variables.y, ..." it will exactly be like when x,y,z are the variables of another module called "global_variables.py"?

Comment: Yes, if you think you want global variables, then creating them in main and passing them around is the way to go.